# How To Fetch And Store List Data In Appium And How To Click On Particular Searched Record

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

[image]
I am trying to fetch and store the list of Year data in list variable but unable to store all data.

And at the same time I also want to search for a particular year and if the year will not find then I want to scroll and search again on the list.

I am also attaching the screenshot of my elements in application.

This is my code for store and search list of record in the list variable

```
public void fetchVehicleListAndClickOnYear(String year) {

        java.util.List<MobileElement> vehicleList =driver.findElementsById(packageName+":id/title"); 

        for (int i=0;i<= vehicleList.size();i++) {
            String actuallist = vehicleList.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println("Print vehicle year list " +actuallist);
            if(actuallist.equals(year)) {
                driver.findElementByName(year).click();
            } else {
                Utils.scrollDown(driver);
            }
        }
    }

    public void fillVehicleInfoOnSignup(String Vehicle_Year) {

        vehicleYearTextBox.click();
        Utils.PauseTestExecution(2);
        fetchVehicleListAndClickOnYear(Vehicle_Year);

    }



For scrolling code 

public static void scrollDown(AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
            //if pressX was zero it didn't work for me
            int pressX = driver.manage().window().getSize().width / 2;
            // 4/5 of the screen as the bottom finger-press point
            int bottomY = driver.manage().window().getSize().height * 4/5;
            // just non zero point, as it didn't scroll to zero normally
            int topY = driver.manage().window().getSize().height / 8;
            //scroll with TouchAction by itself
            scroll(pressX, bottomY, pressX, topY,driver);
        }

        public static void scroll(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY,AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
            TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
            new TouchAction(driver).press(PointOption.point(fromX, fromY)).waitAction().moveTo(PointOption.point(toX, toY)).release().perform();
        }
```

Error showing

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/Users/daffolapmac-73/eclipse-workspace/Wapanda_Driver_Automation/libfiles/cglib-3.2.8.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Print vehicle year list 2018 
Print vehicle year list 2000 
Print vehicle year list 1984 
Print vehicle year list 1967 
Print vehicle year list 1952 
Print vehicle year list 1942 
Print vehicle year list 1941 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out-of-bounds for length 7
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:440)
    at com.wapanda.pages.DriverSignUpPages.fetchVehicleListAndClickOnYear(DriverSignUpPages.java:261)
    at com.wapanda.pages.DriverSignUpPages.fillVehicleInfoOnSignup(DriverSignUpPages.java:275)
    at com.wapanda.tests.ValidateDriverProcess.validateDriverSignupProcess(ValidateDriverProcess.java:108)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error says "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out-of-bounds for length 7".To fix it correct the for loop as following ("<" insdead of "<="). The code would look as following:

```
for (int i=0;i<vehicleList.size();i++) {
            String actuallist = vehicleList.get(i).getText();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Modified code to return list of displayed year. (note: code potentially could be optimized to have a single loop. As the scrolling logic is not clear I kept it as is)

```
public List<String> fetchVehicleListAndClickOnYear(String year) {

    java.util.List<MobileElement> vehicleList =driver.findElementsById(packageName+":id/title");

    java.util.List<String> displayedYears = new ArrayList<>();
    //logic to add displayed years to list
    for (MobileElement yearEl: vehicleList) {
        displayedYears.add(yearEl.getText());
    }

    //logic to click
    for (int i=0;i< vehicleList.size();i++) {
        String actuallist = vehicleList.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println("Print vehicle year list " +actuallist);
        if(actuallist.equals(year)) {
            driver.findElementByName(year).click();
        } else {
            Utils.scrollDown(driver);
        }
    }
    return displayedYears;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, upvoted.  I think Tarum might run into the other problems I mention once the code gets past that oversight, however.  The code scrolls after the very first match is not found.

Comment: @BillHileman really good points about the scroll and list checking in your reply. I didn't think of it that way, will keep in mind and apply for my coding as well ;)

Comment: @VladimirEfimov . Thanks for your reply. But I want to fetch all years currently this is fetching only first year from top section after scrolling.  If I want to click on 2015 then error showing unable to find the element . Can you please suggest solution how i can print all years in list

Comment: @VladimirEfimov Thanks now IndexOutOfBoundsException not coming.

Comment: @TarunDabbs could you please confirm the flow. Am I right that in your case you store the list of currently displayed years to vehicleList variable? So in the beginning, it has 7 years. If the year you need is not present you would like to scroll and take the list of elements again (the new list of years) and try your logic again?

Comment: @VladimirEfimov :- I want to store all years in list currently 7 year is visible so in this condition all 7 should become in list but currently only top 1 is storing in list.Id is same for all years

Comment: @TarunDabbs updated my answer with the code that will return the list of the displayed year. Give it a try ;)

Comment: @VladimirEfimov :- Will try and confirm you Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A list array will only return what is displayed on the device at the time you request the list array.

In your example, the dates 2018 down to 2012 are displayed, so when you initialize the list it will only contain those elements.

When you search for a match in that list, and none is found, you need to call your scroll routine (which I will touch on in a bit) and then re-read the list completely, and start the search again, but before you start searching the list, you need also to make sure that the list you read in again is not the same list that was already there.  You can do that by simply checking the last item in the list.  If it's the same as the last item in the previous list, you reached the end and can exit the loop with a not found condition.

The other thing is your scroll routine, you seem to be trying to scroll from 80% of height to 20% of height (4/5 and 1/8) but the list itself only takes up half of the screen, the lower half.  I recommend that instead you have your starting y position at 80 or 90 percent, and scroll to 70 or 60 percent.  These will be smaller scrolls but it needs to be in the scope of the viewport, so you could try various numbers.

Hope this helps.